# How can I read the values from XML using batch file?

Tags: xml, batch-file

How can I read the values from XML using batch file?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<PARENT>
<FTP>
<SAMPLE>
  <FILE>test.xls</FILE>
  <OUTBOX>testoutbox</OUTBOX>
  <ARCHIVE>location</ARCHIVE>
</SAMPLE>
</FTP>
</PARENT>
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually saw that post but can't work it out a while ago.  What I did was, I copied his XML and used that instead of mine and It works.. so the problem was is my XML.

Comment: You will need to add carriage returns to each value to make it work with the referenced solution. You can try to modify the script to avoid the carriage return check.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:: remove variables starting $
FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set $ 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="

FOR /f "tokens=2-4delims=<>" %%a IN (q26985813.txt) DO (
 IF /i "/%%a"=="%%c" SET "$%%a=%%b"
)

SET $

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q26985813.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Note that the first `for` removes all variables beginning `$` from the environment.

Data is returned in variables `$file`, `$outbox` etc - simply prefixed by the `$` in the obvious place. In this way, the routine will set up the variables it finds in the file; if your tagnames change, so will the variables delivered.

The routine relies on the relavant data lines being indented.